# Calling a Method 1 out of 100 Times

Tags: java, android, andengine

I need a 1 in a 100 chance of some functionality being called. Right now I am using the following code, but it's being called more often than 1% of the time.

```
int randomItem = (int)(Math.random()*100);
if (randomItem >= 90 && randomItem <= 100)
{
    // Do something ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're adding the sprite when the random number is between 90 and 100. This makes a 10% chance. Just test if Math.random() is `< 0.01`.

Comment: So is this the best solution out of all of these? So how does this give a 1 in 100 chance? And lets say i wanted to change it to 20 in 100 chance? would i change it to < .20?

Comment: The javadoc says: *Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0. Returned values are chosen pseudorandomly with (approximately) uniform distribution from that range. *. So yes, you have 1% chance for the random to be < 0.01, and 20% chance for it to be < 0.2

Answer (score 2):

You have to say something like `if (Math.random() * 100 >= 99.0)`, or just without the scaling, `if (Math.random() >= 0.99)`, or with the integer, `if (randomItem == 99)`.

`Math.random()` returns a floating point number in the range `[0.0, 1.0)`, so 100 times this gives you a range `[0.0, 100.0)`, and conversion to integer gives an integer in the range `[0, 100)`.

The conversion to integer may not be necessary if you don't need it for anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace

```
randomItem >= 90 && randomItem <= 100
```

with

```
randomItem == 99
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now you have a 1 int 10 chance. To get a 1 in 100 chance do this:

```
int chance = (int)(100*Math.random())
if (chance == 1) {
    //Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Math.Random` returns a number between 1 and 0. To get a 1% chance you want your code to look somewhat like this:

```
Math.Random() <= 0.01
```

Also, the `nextDouble` method of the `Random` class is used the same way.

```
r.nextDouble() < 0.01; //r is a instance of Random
```

Both of these will give you a 1% chance.